# POSTMAN producing error: error: invalid input syntax for type integer: When trying to send POST reguest

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, postman

My syntax for the postman JSON post reguest is:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "type": "Colonial",
    "Location": 1.1,
    "Postnumber": 1424,
    "City": "Helsinki",
    "Reservation_time": "1112"
}

These column hold values in postgresDB
id = serial
type = varchar
location = point
postnumber = int
City = varchar
Reservation time = varchar
```

I cant figure out what is wrong as the error i get is wrong type for integer.

Edit: added endpoint model and service.

Model:

```
exports.createTila = async (id, type, location, postnumber, city, reservation_time) => {
  try {
    const result = await client.query(
      "INSERT INTO tila (id, type, location, postnumber, city, reservation_time) VALUES$
      [id, type, location, postnumber, city, reservation_time]
    );
    return result.rows;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

Service:

```
exports.createTila = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const tilaObject = request.body;
    const newTila = await tilaModel.createTila(tilaObject);
    response.status(200).send(newTila);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: i think the problem is from `location` with `point` type , i think json should have `latitude` and `longitude` values , not a float number like `1.1`.

Comment: What is the correct JSON syntax for point type?

Comment: i have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table field's, any fields value is going null that's why it throws this exception. And change the fields

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "type": "Colonial",
    "latitude": 1.1,
    "longitude " : 1.1
    "postnumber": 1424,
    "city": "Helsinki",
    "reservation time": "1112"
}
```

here latitude and longitude is of **double precision** type

Comment: changed field "location" as follows: "location": [11241,124124], yet I get the same error.

Comment: have you check fields values?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is from location with `point` type , your json should have `latitude` and `longitude` values , not a float number like 1.1

```
{
   "id":3,
   "type":"Colonial",
   "Location":{
      "latitude":35.55689,
      "longitude":51.54865
   },
   "Postnumber":1424,
   "City":"Helsinki",
   "Reservation time":"1112"
}
```

Comment: Same error is produced with the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error:

Instead of creating an object in service like this

```
exports.createTila = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const tilaObject = request.body;
    const newTila = await tilaModel.createTila(tilaObject);
    response.status(200).send(newTila);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

I need to define the values of db columns in service aswell, like this:

```
exports.createTila = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const {id, type, location, postnumber, city, reservation_time} = request.body;
    const newTila = await tilaModel.createTila(id, type, location, postnumber, city, reservation_time);
    response.status(200).send(newTila);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```